# Properties of a mvvm class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvvm

I have a simple view with some data to insert/update in database and I need to show some message after save it.
My doubt is: should this message be a property of my mvvm class? or should I put it into ViewBag/ViewData?

Comment: When you say "should this message be a property", what do you mean "this message", Messagebox, label with a string?  What code are you using to show the message?

Comment: @jimmyjambles the message is a span element which contains a sucess's saved message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to store the message as a property on your view model. You could have a property on your view model which indicates whether the operation succeeded or not. Then inside the view test this property and display the message:

```
@if (Model.Saved)
{
    <div>The item was saved</div>
}
```

and inside the controller action that performs the save you will set the property to true.